# How do you write non-blocking modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, nonblocking

Coming from an entirely different background, the way Node.js works is still a very foreign concept to me. I'm grasping the *concept* of using callbacks in your functions, but it's hard for me to actually put this into practice when I'm trying to support modular development and as a result better scaling.

For example, how would I return the results of a function back to my code, or rather, access without blocking? I've been reading up on it, but I just can't wrap my head around how this is accomplished, as everybody is giving me a different answer. Take a log function, for example:

```
exports.log = function (req, res, type) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You write your function so that it allows the caller to pass in a callback to be invoked when the operation is complete.

Comment: That's an incredibly simple explanation for an incredibly simple problem. That removed all of my doubt. Thank you. I would give you your points if I could.

Comment: basically, anything you used to do "under" a call, you still do under the call, but you pad that code with ",function(){" and "})"...

Comment: Yes, it's logical now that I think about it. I'm not sure why it took me so long to grasp.

Comment: Just because a function takes a callback does not make it non-blocking(asynchronous).  Any async code that needs to return you to program flow however, needs to take a callback parameter.  Writing non-blocking code is more about proper general use of nodejs across the board.  You can write very bad, blocking functions, that take a callback parameter.

Comment: Of course. Giving a man a blacksmith's tools doesn't mean he can craft a proper sword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function doStuff (someValue, someOtherValue, someCallBack) {
    console.log("First Value: " + someValue);

    while(someValue-- != 0) {console.log(someValue);}
    someCallBack(someOtherValue);
}

function delayEventLoopMore(someValue) {

    while(someValue-- != 0) {console.log('The value:' + someValue);}
}

doStuff(100000, 100000, delayEventLoopMore);

console.log('YAY!');
```

The previous code is an example of blocking code involving callbacks.  Clearly simply providing the callback parameter has not made this code non-blocking.  If you run it you should clearly see two different counts down from 100,000 to 0, and then finally printing 'YAY'.  If this function were non blocking, we would certainly have had plenty of time to print 'Yay'.  If you doubt this feel free to increase the values to millions or even billions.  'Yay' will always be the last thing printed.

True async, non-blocking behavior comes from the V8 backend.  The only way to replicate this is to produce a native extension.

Here are two versions of this function:

```
exports.log = function (someFileName) {
    var results;

    results = fs.readFileSync(someFileName);

    return results;
}


exports.log = function (someFileName, callback) {
    var results;


    fs.readFile(someFileName, function(data) {
        results = data;//unnecessary just for clarity!
        callback(results);
    }
}
```

The first version assumes that whatever operations you are doing are synhcronous.  There is absolutely no benefit to using a callback in this situation.  Just return the results.  It will result in the exact same amount of delay in the event loop either way.  If the work that you have to do here is very CPU intensive, you're probably stuck with this.

If it is I/O intensive, you can do one of two things.  A: take advantage of node modules already developed that are Async: http, fs, there's some good mongodb stuff, etc... or if nothing exists for your use case, develop a native extension for it.  Regardless, the way you then return the results, is by taking a callback the user supplied you, and calling this callback with the contents of 'results' you have built up over the course of  your asynchronous operations.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of trouble for some simple modular development. It doesn't sound very scalable either. Is there no way around this? Are you forced to writing your entire application in a single file?

Comment: No, you don't have to write your application in a single file.  The trick is to identify the operation in your code that takes time, and make it asynchronous.  In this case a very simple native extension that launches a thread to count down from "someLargeNumber" to zero, would produce the desired effect.  But work that is like counting down from zero, will occupy 100% of a processor core, no matter how it is coded, and no matter the language, because there is no waiting on Memory, or disk.  So this may be a bad example, just something I drummed up real quick.

Comment: More information on your use case would help me point you in the right direction!

Comment: So in the end it all boils down to whether you use synchronous functions or asynchronous function that make your functions synchronous or asynchronous?

One example I have right now is to establish a database connection and manipulate and store some details from the request. I could do it in a single block, but I prefer to keep my things modular, coming from an OOP background.

Comment: Precisely!  There is no inherent Node magic, that will allow you to make something asynchronous, unless you're willing to develop your own Native C++ code, or a find a library which has done so for you.

Comment: All right, neat. Thanks. But even if, and this might be somewhat off-topic, isn't a single thread problematic when speaking of a horizontally scaling application? Surely the processing times must increase by quite a bit as you get more users.

Comment: Node is only single threaded at the scripting level.  The V8 backend launches many threads for many of its operations.  Otherwise nothing in node would be asynchronous and you would be exactly right, fortunately you are not.  Although, nothing will ever be as fast as writing it in pure native code, Node does a very good job, and in my opinion the simplicity in design you gain is well worth it!

Comment: Your welcome, this may or may not help you with your use case: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native